# Add extra field in Django QuerySet as timedelta type

Tags: sql, django, orm, django-queryset

I have the following model:

```
class UptimeManager(models.Manager):
    def with_length(self):
        """Get querySet of uptimes sorted by length including the current one. """
        extra_length = Uptime.objects.extra(select={'length':
            """
            SELECT
                IF (end is null,
                timestampdiff(second,begin,now()),
                timestampdiff(second,begin,end))
            FROM content_uptime c
            WHERE content_uptime.id = c.id
            """
            })
        return extra_length


class Uptime(models.Model):
    begin = models.DateTimeField('beginning')
    end = models.DateTimeField('end', null=True) I call
    host = models.ForeignKey("Host")
    objects = UptimeManager()
    ...
```

then I call `Uptime.objects.with_length().order_by('-length')[:10]` to get list of longest uptimes.

But the `length` in template is of integer type. How to modify my code as the length of object returned by manager would be accessible in template as `timedelta` object?

I almost could do it by returning a list and converting number of seconds to `timedelta` objects, but then I have to do sorting, filtering etc. in my Python code which is rather ineffective in comparison to one well done SQL query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is to create a filter that determines type of length var and returns timedelta in case it's some integer type

```
from django import template
import datetime

register = template.Library()

def timedelta(value):
    if isinstance(value, (long,int)):
        return datetime.timedelta(seconds=value)
    elif isinstance(value, datetime.timedelta):
        return value
    else: raise UnsupportedOperation

register.filter('timedelta',timedelta)
```

and use in template it's trivial 
`{{ uptime.length|timedelta }}`

Answer (score 1):

[Add a property](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/aug/18/django-tips-using-properties-models-and-managers/) to the model that looks at the actual field and converts it to the appropriate type.

Comment: But where exactly should I use a property? Cause I'm rather a newbie at Django so I can see it ;)